# How to show loading on selection change

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

Using some generic terminology for the question.

I periodically poll student list for selected class. When user selects a student in the selected class, I store the student id and retrieve it next time user selects the same class.

This means that each class has a selected student persisted in DB.

Whenever user switches between class, i'm able to retrieve all the data as expected but the problem is with the loading indication:
Loading/spinner appears only the first time. When user select the second time, student list and selected student from previous class stays on the screen until response for this newly selected class is received .

FYI,
`selectedClassId$` is a multicast observable that gives selected class id.
`studentList$` is a multicast observable that polls students for selected class id.

Service implementation

```
// -------------- class.service.ts ---------------
public readonly selectedClassId$ = this.selectedClass$.pipe(
        map((value) => value?.id),
        shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
    );

// ------------ students.service.ts ----------

// contains compelete student list
public readonly studentList$: Observable<Student[] | never>;

// contains id of last selected student so UI can automatically select next time.
// I can use it where i need just the id
public readonly selectedStudentId$: Observable<string | never>;

// contains complete object of last selected student
// i can use it where i need complerte object of student
public readonly selectedStudent$: Observable<Student | never>;

constructor() {
    this.studentList$ = this.getStudentListPolling();
    this.selectedStudentId$ = this.getLastSelectedStudentId();
    this.selectedStudent$ = this.getLastSelectedStudent();
}

private getStudentListPolling(): Observable<Student[] | never> {
    return this.classService.selectedClassId$.pipe(
      filter((classId) => !!classId),
      switchMap((classId) => this.pollStudents(classId)),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
    );
  }

private pollStudents(classId: string): Observable<Student[]> {
    return timer(0, StudentService.pollingInterval).pipe(
      concatMap(() => this.fetchStudentListFromBE(classId)),
      distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)
    );
  }

private getLastSelectedStudentId(): Observable<string | never> {
    return this.classService.selectedClassId$.pipe(
      filter((classId) => !!classId),

// fetchLastSelectedStudentIdFromBE gives the student id that user had previously  selected for this class
      switchMap((classId) => return this.fetchLastSelectedStudentIdFromBE()),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
    );
  }

private getLastSelectedStudent(): Observable<Student | never> {
    return this.selectedStudentId$.pipe(
      mergeMap((studentId) => {
        if (studentId) {
          return this.studentList$.pipe(
            take(1),
            map(students => students.find(student => student.id === studentId)),
          );
        }
        return of(undefined);
      }),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
    );
  }
```

Now user can change his selection and select a different class.
I have to show the students list and selected student in the component like this.

component.ts

```
interface StudentData {
  studentList: Student[];
  selectedStudent?: Student;
}


  public readonly studentData$: Observable<StudentData >;

constructor(
    private readonly studentService: StudentService
  ) {
    this.studentData$ = this.getStudentData();
  }

public getStudentData(): Observable<StudentData> {
    return combineLatest([
      this.studentService.studentList$,
      this.studentService.selectedStudentId$
    ]).pipe(
      map(([students, selectedStudentId]) => {
        const studentData: StudentData = {
          studentList: students
        }
        if (students?.length > 0) {
          studentData.selectedStudent = students.find(student => student.id === selectedStudentId);
        }
        return studentData;
      })
    );
  }
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="studentData$ | async as studentData; else loadingOrError">
// show data
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loadingOrError>
  <div
    class="idemia-row idemia-box m-0"
    *ngIf="!hasError"
  >
    <mat-spinner
      [diameter]="50"
      [strokeWidth]="5"
    ></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Any idea how I can show loading when user selects the second or third or subsequent times.

Comment: You're missing something.  In the html template you're data source is **reportData$**, but I don't see where **reportData$** is a component and how it connects to the rest of the code.  Is it **studentData$**?

Comment: Yes, its studentData$. Forgot to rename it